# Post not redirecting to non www after changing from www

Tags: urls

Recently I changed my domain from www to non-www, still Post accessing using www. But showing blank page, what to do ? So that all post redirect to non-www. I did it through cpanel, after that everything is fine except 12-15 post not redirecting, still accessing through www and showing blank page,  it's only 12-15 post among 90 post, why so, and how to solve this, thanks. Also used redirect plugin, rank math SEO plugin redirect module.

Comment: Please include the contents of your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

> I did it through cpanel

That's certainly part of the problem. cPanel will add the redirect at the end of the `.htaccess` file (after the WordPress front-controller) - so they are not getting processed. You need to manually edit the `.htaccess` file to move these directives to the top.

However, that doesn't entirely answer your question as this wouldn't affect only "some" WordPress pages.

Accessing your site with the `www` subdomain should still show the relevant page - not a blank page?!